# How to set image fit on every screen with aspect ratio

Tags: android, imageview

I have some Images, coming from the the server, I am confuced regarding image resolution. how it is possible to show every image complete on every screen with the aspect ratio.

I need to cover the entire screen with no crop. Image should be complete on every resolution screen.

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Image coming from server

```
Picasso.with(context).load(shopDataForAdvs.get(position).getSrc()).fit().placeholder(R.drawable.product_image).error(R.drawable.product_image).into(imageView);
```

Here I have Image which is streaching

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to make every image fit every aspect ratio without either stretching, cropping, or letterboxing. I'd recommend trying `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to upgrade my comment to an answer...

Every image has an aspect ratio. Every phone has an aspect ratio. There is no guarantee that these two aspect ratios will be the same, so you have three options:

1 - Stretch the image to fit. This is what `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and the Picasso `fit()` call are doing. I don't really recommend this choice, as the image will look "weird", but it is a valid choice.

2 - Crop the image to fit. This would be `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and Picasso `centerCrop()`. This will scale the image up (without stretching it) until the smallest dimension of the image matches the dimension of the phone, and will crop the image in the other dimension.

3 - Letterboxing. This would be `android:scaleType="centerInside"` or Picasso `centerInside()`. This will scale the image up (without stretching it) until the largest dimension of the image matches the dimension of the phone, and will leave the rest of the ImageView blank.

I recommend option 2, or perhaps a combination of options 3 and 2 (load the image without cropping, but let the user zoom in if they desire).

Comment: You could also choose to use letterboxing with a color that "matches" the image, so that the solid color behind the image isn't as obvious as a black or white would be

Comment: Awesome explanation. thank you so much for clearing all possible ways to handle this scenario